# How to change LTR wordpress themes to RTL

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

hi all I want to change my wordpress theme's writing system from left to right to right to left for Persian Language . What I should do ? I know somethings about this like translate words with Poedit and ... but my problem is in CSS ! Please Help me thanks a lot [I'm sorry for my poor english :( ]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RTLCSS Online](http://rtlcss.com/playground/) for transforming CSS from Left-To-Right(LTR) to Right-To-Left(RTL)

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy 
Just got to Appearance > editor
Then open the header.php file and add the dir attribute to the html tag

```
<html dir="RTL">
```

Answer (score 0):

Within CSS it can be as simple as:

```
html, body {direction:rtl;}
```

This can have adverse effects on the layout however as a site for example with a logo on the left and a menu on the right would now be completely the other way around.

As long as the layout fits both ways (may require a little tweaking) this usually works well enough for me.

Possible tweaks:

#### LTR

```
#main-content {display:block; float:left; width:750px; margin-right:20px;}
#sidebar {display:block; float:left; width:250px;}
```

#### RTL

```
 #main-content {display:block; float:left; width:750px; margin-right:0;}
 #sidebar {display:block; float:left; width:250px; margin-right:20px;}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is enough ? for other Id and Classes ?

Comment: I said it can be as simple as the code above. You will need to add some CSS specific element styles too. For example if you had a main column column on the left and a sidebar on the right you may have to edit those styles for the RTL site. I have updated my answer to reflect this.